# Ruby, Textile: how to get plain text without tags and textile format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highlighting, textile, redcloth

I have articles with bodies that are textile formatted text. I make full text search with sphinx and I want to highlight query in results. Sphinx give me something like this

```
A *simple* _<span class="highlight">example</span>_.
```

I want to remove all textile format but save highlight tags, like this

```
A simple <span class="highlight">example</span>.
```

Is it possible with Redcloth gem?

Answer (score 3):

You could process the content with RedCloth and then strip the result of all tags. So something like:

```
strip_tags (RedCloth.new(simple_input).to_html)
```

strip_tags is available in the ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper module. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/strip_tags for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, strip_tags dose not save any special tag

Comment: This  method has been deprecated in the helper you gave and is now in http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Have yet to work with Sphinx, but judging from your question, it appears that `<span class="highlight">..</span>` is added by Sphinx upon outputting the text as a search result.

I am currently unaware of any method in RedCloth, but the [Vidibus-Textile Gem](https://github.com/vidibus/vidibus-textile) (based on RedCloth) adds a `to_text` method, which could be useful for your case.

Ofc you'd need to make sure it's invoked *before* Sphinx adds the `span` tags.

Comment: Also, defining a custom input pattern (see http://redcloth.org/faq) might be an option. Though it'd seem kind of unclean to consider `<span class="highlight">..</span>` as textile pattern being processed to back to itself :)